# Garbage Collector Flash Player

Tags: flash, memory-management, garbage-collection

Is there a way to force the flash garbage collector to clean up freed memory? I've seen that it takes a lot of time for flash to clean up not referenced memory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't. It's something Grant Skinner has written lots about, so check [his blog](http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/06/as3_resource_ma.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can add things to your own garbage collector and then whipe them as they complete.

```
var antiGC:Dictionary = new Dictionary(false);

var loaderwidth:Tween = new Tween(maskbox, "width", Regular.easeIn, 1, 1000, 25, false);


antiGC[loaderwidth] = loaderwidth;

loaderwidth.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, lwfinished);

function lwfinished(e:TweenEvent){

    loaderwidth.removeEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, lwfinished);
    antiGC[e.currentTarget] = null;
    delete antiGC[e.currentTarget];
}
```